# Is there a way to give a user access to different columns on different rows of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant, row-level-security

Is there a way to give a PostgreSQL user access to a different columns on different rows of a table?  For example in the following table, is there some combination of `GRANT` or `POLICY` or ??? that would only allow the user to view the "allowed" cells?

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INT,
  col_a TEXT,
  col_b TEXT
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
  (1, 'allowed', 'allowed'),
  (2, 'allowed', 'forbidden')
;
```

I think it can be done by splitting the columns in to different tables, but is it possible with only a single table?

---

One possible solution suggested by O. Jones - use a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_secure_view AS
SELECT
  id,
  col_a,
  CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN col_b ELSE NULL END AS col_b
FROM my_table;

GRANT SELECT ON my_secure_view TO whatever_user;
REVOKE SELECT ON my_table FROM whatever_user;
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a `VIEW` containing the rows and columns you allow your user to see, then granting the user SELECT access to the view but not the underlying table.

For example

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_secure_view AS
SELECT allowedcol1, allowedcol2
  FROM my_table
 WHERE col_b <> 'forbidden';

GRANT SELECT ON my_secure_view TO whatever_user;
REVOKE SELECT ON my_table TO whatever_user;
```

You can also, if you wish, write stored procedures and grant access to them to the users you choose, while revoking access to the underlying tables.

Comment: This answer doesn't quite work because whatever_user can't see the "allowed" value of `col_a` in row #2. It does suggest a solution though...

Comment: You should probably create the view using `WITH (security_barrier)`: http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2012/03/security-barrier-views.html